# toCharArray() Python Equivalent

Tags: c#, python, string, char

Is there a function similar to toCharArray(c#) in python? I know there aren't chars in python, but is there a similar data type? Or is there a way to break a string up into smaller, one digit strings?

Comment: Simple `list(your_string_here)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by char array, you mean a set of integers (as opposed to one-character strings), then you would do the following:

```
list(mystring.encode())
```

(for python3)